# What is the special fields in rust's protobuf crate?

Tags: rust, protocol-buffers

This is my `proto3` file

```
syntax = "proto3";

message SyncRequest { string path = 1; }
```

And I suppose there would only be one field in the struct `SyncRequest`.

```rust
pub struct SyncRequest {
    // message fields
    // @@protoc_insertion_point(field:SyncRequest.path)
    pub path: ::std::string::String,
    // special fields
    // @@protoc_insertion_point(special_field:SyncRequest.special_fields)
    pub special_fields: ::protobuf::SpecialFields,
}
```

But actually there are special fields here including the `UnknowFields` and `CacheSize`. I don't know whether I should initialize them.

I have no idea what is `SpecialFields` used for, and the only way I can construct a new instance of `SyncRequest` seems to be

```rust
let mut req = file_sync::SyncRequest::new();
req.path = "tmp/a.txt".to_string();
```

There is no methond like `req.set_path()`, which I just found in some another articles.

Maybe these fields are the stuff I should not care about or I can just ignore them. Is this right ?

Comment: Yes you shouldn't usually have to care about that. It's for the `protobuf` crate to be able to store unknown fields in case the program goes out of sync with the `.proto` definition. `protobuf` doesn't generate any getter or setter methods afaik. `prost` generates them for enum fields. You can set the fields directly.